# Using ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I want to create a web application using ASP.NET MVC. I saw a web application that was similar to a windows application. For example: it was used TextBox, Listview, Treeview, TabControl, GridView, Button, etc. in web application.

I've researched in the internet but all examples used HTML tag to create TextBox, Button, etc.

How can I use .Net Controls directly in ASP.NET MVC web application?

Comment: You should render through your views the controls you want. MVC doesn't have Controls as WebForms or WinForms.

Comment: I suggest you start with this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot directly** use a .Net control inside ASP.net MVC application instead use some plugins to make things done.

List out all .Net Controls that your windows application contains.

Mostly frequently used controls will have plugins else add it as a **custom control** in your asp.net MVC application.